# Demoiselle-Nimble: Erro ao gerar CRUD Vaadin

Tags: java, demoiselle, demoiselle-nimble

Estou utilizando a classe abaixo, Banco.java, abaixo:

```
@Entity
public class Banco implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="banco_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "banco_seq_gen", sequenceName = "banco_id_seq",allocationSize=1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @TextField
    @Field(prompt = "{banco.prompt.numero}", label = "{banco.label.numero}")
    @NotNull(message = "{banco.numero.erro.null}")
    private String numero;

    @Column
    @TextField
    @Field(prompt = "{banco.prompt.descricao}", label = "{banco.label.description}")
    @NotNull(message = "{banco.descricao.erro.null}")
    private String descricao;

    public Banco() {
        super();    
    }

    public Banco(String numero, String descricao) {     
        this.numero = numero;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    // Getters and setter omitidos!
}
```

E o mesmo está dando o seguinte erro:

```
INFO  FROM: C:\Demoiselle\ide\eclipse-4.4.1\plugins\br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.eclipse_1.2.0\templates\generate-crud-vaadin\src\main\resources\messages_en.properties.fragment.groovy
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.util.ParserUtil.getClassAttributesFromFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [C:\Demoiselle\workspace\vaadinfinance/src/main/java/br/com/djsystem/domain/Banco.java]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1370)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1356)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at SimpleTemplateScript2.run(SimpleTemplateScript2.groovy:5)
    at groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate$1.writeTo(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:165)
    at groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate$1.toString(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.template.GroovyTemplate.applyTemplate(GroovyTemplate.groovy:58)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.template.Template$applyTemplate.call(Unknown Source)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.util.TemplateUtil.applyTemplate(TemplateUtil.groovy:58)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.util.TemplateUtil$applyTemplate.call(Unknown Source)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.DemoiselleNimble$_applyTemplates_closure5.doCall(DemoiselleNimble.groovy:314)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachFileRecurse(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:980)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachFileRecurse(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:978)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachFileRecurse(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:978)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachFileRecurse(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:978)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachFileRecurse(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1212)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$763.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.DemoiselleNimble.applyTemplates(DemoiselleNimble.groovy:293)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.DemoiselleNimble$applyTemplates.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.gui.wizard.tools.TemplateVariablesStep2.finish(TemplateVariablesStep2.groovy:159)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.gui.wizard.tools.TemplateVariablesStep2$finish.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.gui.wizard.GenericWizardFrame$_footer_closure1.doCall(GenericWizardFrame.groovy:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Teste na versão 2 e 3 da infra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente é um "bug" no template de geração do Vaadin. Mas bastante simples de resolver.
Esse template gera os atributos no arquivo /src/main/resources/messages_en.properties que é criado com o arquétipo Maven do Demoiselle para uma aplicação com Vaadin.
Como o nome indica é um arquivo de mensagens para internacionalizar a aplicação utilizando como opção a lingua inglesa (_en). Como é um template, o resultado não é exatamente uma tradução de qualidade, mas apenas as entradas das propriedades que deverão ser traduzidas manualmente. Mesmo o arquivo para língua portuguesa gera as entradas de forma mecânica baseada no nomes dos atributos da classe pojo. Essas propriedades devem ser corrigidas também para melhor apresentação. O que se ganha neste processo é o trabalho de criar os atributos e no caso dos templates JSF de vinculá-los nas páginas XHTML. Inclusive, agora percebi, que o template para português também está com um problema.

um dos objetivos dos templates do Demoiselle-Nimble,é que eles sejam apenas uma amostra do que pode ser feito. Pois é possível e incentivado que o próprio desenvolvedor customize e melhore conforme suas necessidades.

Por ser erro no template, não é preciso esperar a correção pois, como comentei, você mesmo pode fazer isso no seu ambiente.

Mesmo assim, peço que registre o bug no tracker do projeto: http://tracker.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br

Podemos considerar a correção em dois caminhos:

- 1) Você não tem interesse em internacionalizar a aplicação, portanto quer ignorar esse arquivo: Desta forma basta excluir os arquivos de templates:

  C:\Demoiselle\ide\eclipse-4.4.1\plugins\br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.eclipse_1.2.0\templates\generate-crud-vaadin\src\main\resources\messages_en.properties.fragment.groovy

  e

  C:\Demoiselle\ide\eclipse-4.4.1\plugins\br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.eclipse_1.2.0\templates\generate-crud-vaadin\src\main\resources\messages_en.properties.fragment.groovy.conf
- 2) Você quer gerar o arquivo para internacionalizar a aplicação.

Para corrigir mude o conteúdo do arquivo:
C:\Demoiselle\ide\eclipse-4.4.1\plugins\br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.eclipse_1.2.0\templates\generate-crud-vaadin\src\main\resources\messages_en.properties.fragment.groovy para:

```
    menu.new.${bean} = ${pojo}
<%

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.util.ParserUtil as RU
def tmpFile = new File(beanPath+beanJavaName)
def attrList = RU.getAttributesFromClassFile(tmpFile)
   if (!attrList.isEmpty()) {
        attrList.each() { attrName, attrValue -> 
            String attrLow = attrName.toLowerCase() 
    %>
    ${bean}.label.${attrLow} = ${attrName}
    ${bean}.prompt.${attrLow} = ${pojo}'s ${attrName}
    <%
        }
    } else {
    %>
    ${bean}.label.text = Text
    ${bean}.prompt.text = ${pojo}'s Text 
    <%
}
%>
```

O problema no template para portugues é que o conteúdo é o mesmo do outro. Inclusive há um bug no arquétipo que gera o arquivo pois está em "inglês" também. Mude o C:\Demoiselle\ide\eclipse-4.4.1\plugins\br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.eclipse_1.2.0\templates\generate-crud-vaadin\src\main\resources\messages.properties.fragment.groovy
para:

```
    menu.new.${bean} = ${pojo}
<%

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.tools.nimble.util.ParserUtil as RU
def tmpFile = new File(beanPath+beanJavaName)
def attrList = RU.getAttributesFromClassFile(tmpFile)
   if (!attrList.isEmpty()) {
        attrList.each() { attrName, attrValue -> 
            String attrLow = attrName.toLowerCase() 
    %>
    ${bean}.label.${attrLow} = ${attrName}
    ${bean}.prompt.${attrLow} = ${attrName} do ${pojo} 
    <%
        }
    } else {
    %>
    ${bean}.label.text = Texto
    ${bean}.prompt.text = Texto do ${pojo}
    <%
}
%>
```

Com essas dicas, você pode dar uma olhada nos outros templates e se quiser fazer suas melhorias.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, alterei os arquivos como informado!